# Make a long string have a max length trying to keep its sense

Tags: php

I have a long string stored in a variable, this string is a description of a video, it can be empty or super long. What I need is to make it that if it is longer that 100 characters for example, show only first 100 characters, but without cutting words out and, if possible, sentences should be kept too. So depending on how long and sentences are, but max lenght possible will be 100 characters. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Is the description HTML or pure text?

Comment: @JvdBerg: I tried only counting till last dot before 100th character, but there may be urls so I am stuck in here. @ Michael: its just text.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the string is longer than 100 characters where the last ., ? or ! is (within the first 100 characters) and cut everything after the dot off.

Comment: I cannot be sure that it will have dots. In many cases it does not.

Comment: Then you cannot cut the string currectly and keeping it's semantic meaning - unless you're implementing a semantic parser which is not..."that easy" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:
 1. Check if the string has over 100 characters
 2. If it does, check for example from 90-100 and search for an ending of a sentence and cut there
 3. If there is no complete sentence, go backwards from 100 and look for a space and cut there.